# MySQL: Limitar el número de resultados en función de un GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, limit

Tengo la siguiente consulta para, dada una lista de canciones, determinar qué subestilos musicales son los más habituales:

```
SELECT
    id_lista_youtube,
    nombre_subestilo, 
    count(id_subestilo) AS numero_subestilos
FROM
    listas_youtube
        NATURAL JOIN incluidas
            NATURAL JOIN canciones
                NATURAL JOIN discos
                    NATURAL JOIN relacionados
                        NATURAL JOIN subestilos
GROUP BY
    id_lista_youtube,
    nombre_subestilo
ORDER BY
    id_lista_youtube,
    numero_subestilos DESC";
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
id_lista_youtube, nombre_subestilo, numero_subestilos
25, Post-Rock, 13
25, Slowcore, 4
25, Math Rock, 3
25, Dream Pop, 3
25, Post-Metal, 2
25, Ambient, 2
25, Indie Rock, 2
25, Folk Rock, 2
25, Atmospheric Sludge Metal, 2
25, Post-Hardcore, 1
25, Ambient Pop, 1
25, Glitch, 1
25, Experimental Rock, 1
25, Spoken Word, 1
25, Shoegaze, 1
25, Chamber Music, 1
25, Art Rock, 1
26, Britpop, 14
26, Alternative Rock, 6
26, Power Pop, 5
26, Indie Rock, 4
26, Neo-Psychedelia, 3
26, Chamber Pop, 2
26, Glam Rock, 2
26, Progressive Pop, 2
26, Pop Punk, 1
26, Synthpop, 1
26, Art Rock, 1
26, Indie Pop, 1
26, New Wave, 1
26, Dream Pop, 1
26, Post-Punk, 1
26, Alternative Dance, 1
26, Noise Pop, 1
26, Punk Rock, 1
27, Power Pop, 15
27, Alternative Rock, 9
27, Jangle Pop, 5
27, Alt-Country, 1
27, Pop Punk, 1
27, Psychedelic Pop, 1
27, Surf Punk, 1
27, Indie Pop, 1
27, Paisley Underground, 1
27, Vocal Surf, 1
27, Indie Rock, 1
27, Britpop, 1
27, Garage Rock, 1
27, Punk Rock, 1
27, Surf Rock, 1
28, Synthpop, 8
28, Alternative Dance, 5
28, New Wave, 5
28, Indietronica, 3
28, Dance-Punk, 3
28, Indie Pop, 3
28, Neo-Psychedelia, 3
28, Indie Rock, 2
28, New Romantic, 2
28, House, 2
28, Baggy/Madchester, 2
28, Electropop, 2
28, Dub, 2
28, Post-Punk, 2
28, Psychedelic Pop, 1
28, Ambient Pop, 1
28, Disco, 1
28, Riot Grrrl, 1
28, Soul, 1
28, Alternative Rock, 1
28, Big Beat, 1
28, Electroclash, 1
28, UK Hip Hop, 1
28, Art Pop, 1
28, Dream Pop, 1
28, Funk Rock, 1
28, Trip Hop, 1
28, Shoegaze, 1
28, Funk, 1
29, Atmospheric Sludge Metal, 8
29, Post-Metal, 6
29, Post-Rock, 5
29, Progressive Metal, 4
29, Alternative Metal, 4
29, Sludge Metal, 3
29, Hard Rock, 3
29, Heavy Metal, 2
29, Post-Hardcore, 2
29, Blackgaze, 1
29, Mathcore, 1
29, Drone Metal, 1
29, Garage Rock, 1
29, Rap Metal, 1
29, Progressive Rock, 1
29, Punk Rock, 1
29, Rock & Roll, 1
29, Shoegaze, 1
29, Stoner Metal, 1
29, Alternative Rock, 1
29, Noise Rock, 1
29, Speed Metal, 1
29, Melodic Death Metal, 1
29, Doom Metal, 1
29, Funk Metal, 1
30, Indie Pop, 9
30, Jangle Pop, 6
30, Sophisti-Pop, 5
30, New Wave, 4
30, Art Pop, 3
30, Pop Rock, 3
30, Twee Pop, 3
30, Synthpop, 2
30, Dream Pop, 2
30, Ambient Pop, 2
30, Chamber Pop, 2
30, Lounge, 2
30, Indietronica, 1
30, Alternative Rock, 1
30, Pop Soul, 1
30, C86, 1
30, Indie Rock, 1
30, Glitch Pop, 1
30, Post-Punk, 1
30, Sunshine Pop, 1
30, Jazz Pop, 1
30, New Romantic, 1
30, Folktronica, 1
30, Noise Pop, 1
30, Singer/Songwriter, 1
31, Punk Rock, 8
31, Hardcore Punk, 5
31, Art Punk, 3
31, Post-Hardcore, 3
31, Post-Punk, 3
31, Noise Rock, 2
31, Power Pop, 2
31, Hard Rock, 2
31, Garage Rock, 1
31, Anarcho-Punk, 1
31, Garage Punk, 1
31, Glam Punk, 1
31, Gothic Rock, 1
31, Punk Blues, 1
31, Rock & Roll, 1
31, Skate Punk, 1
31, Psychobilly, 1
31, Reggae, 1
31, Alternative Rock, 1
31, Funk Rock, 1
31, Horror Punk, 1
31, Surf Punk, 1
32, Indie Folk, 9
32, Singer/Songwriter, 7
32, Folk Rock, 7
32, Indie Rock, 6
32, Chamber Pop, 4
32, Lo-Fi Indie, 3
32, Indie Pop, 3
32, Chamber Folk, 3
32, Americana, 2
32, Contemporary Folk, 2
32, Slowcore, 2
32, Jangle Pop, 2
32, Psychedelic Folk, 2
32, Psychedelic Pop, 1
32, Post-Rock, 1
32, Dream Pop, 1
32, Post-Punk, 1
32, Folk Pop, 1
32, Anti Folk, 1
32, Gothic Rock, 1
32, Neo-Psychedelia, 1
32, Baroque Pop, 1
32, Piano Rock, 1
32, Art Rock, 1
32, Brass Band, 1
32, Pop Rock, 1
```

¿Habría forma de aplicar un `LIMIT 3` por cada `id_lista_youtube` para filtrar los tres subestilos más habituales por lista?

Es decir:

```
id_lista_youtube, nombre_subestilo, numero_subestilos
25, Post-Rock, 13
25, Slowcore, 4
25, Math Rock, 3
26, Britpop, 14
26, Alternative Rock, 6
26, Power Pop, 5
27, Power Pop, 15
27, Alternative Rock, 9
27, Jangle Pop, 5
28, Synthpop, 8
28, Alternative Dance, 5
28, New Wave, 5
29, Atmospheric Sludge Metal, 8
29, Post-Metal, 6
29, Post-Rock, 5
30, Indie Pop, 9
30, Jangle Pop, 6
30, Sophisti-Pop, 5
31, Punk Rock, 8
31, Hardcore Punk, 5
31, Art Punk, 3
32, Indie Folk, 9
32, Singer/Songwriter, 7
32, Folk Rock, 7
```

Comment: Puedes usar la sentencia Having [revisa aquí](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

Comment: Pero no me asegura que vaya a filtrar sólo los tres primeros, sino aquellos que sean superiores a tal cifra.

Comment: Si usas una versión moderna de mySQL (8 o superior), es muy fácil de conseguir con funciones de ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción para MySql 8.0 o superior podría ser utilizar windows functions para enumerar las filas (particionando por id_lista_youtube y ordenando por numero_subestilos DESC; columna orden) y luego filtrar aquellas filas cuyo orden es <= 3.

```
WITH sqNS AS (SELECT id_lista_youtube, nombre_subestilo, count(id_subestilo) AS numero_subestilos
              FROM listas_youtube
              NATURAL JOIN incluidas
              NATURAL JOIN canciones
              NATURAL JOIN discos
              NATURAL JOIN relacionados
              NATURAL JOIN subestilos
              GROUP BY id_lista_youtube, nombre_subestilo),

     sqOrden AS (SELECT *,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_lista_youtube ORDER BY numero_subestilos DESC) AS orden
                  FROM sqNS)
                  
SELECT id_lista_youtube, nombre_subestilo, numero_subestilos
FROM sqOrden
WHERE orden <= 3
ORDER BY id_lista_youtube, numero_subestilos DESC;
```